# Wordpress: get sessions by user id with token/verify

Tags: wordpress, session, token, verify

In my case, I'm without a "current_user", and I have to retrieve user sessions (with verify token) by user id.

Answer (score 0):

This function return an array of sessions for the user with user_id:

```
public static function get_user_sessions($user_id) {
    $sessions = get_user_meta($user_id, 'session_tokens', true);
    if (!is_array($sessions)) {
        return array();
    }
    return $sessions;
}
```